# Script that uses new directory

Tags: shell-script

I have a script that I need to run an application which, at the end, changes the working directory.  (I'm modifying an ".sh" script and am new to Unix.) I then need to run some commands in that new directory.  I won't know what the directory will be before running the application.  If I run the script as I would run things myself, the directory doesn't change until after I've run the entire script. I'd like to do this about a dozen times in a row so I'd rather not wait (sometimes hours) for each step to run another separate script myself.

Is there a way to run the application, have the directory change, then run additional work in that directory all in one go?

Edit: Here's the basics of my script.   dset takes a parameter (ex. "10") and puts me in a directory.  I create a subdirectory "../10" adjacent to it and move files to that new subdirectory.

```
. dset 10
mkdir ../10
mv tmp.out ../10
```

Comment: Can you post your script?

Comment: Added it. @L.Ray

Comment: Long story short - you can't `cd` in a script unless you're sourcing it.

Comment: So, there's no way to run a series of scripts or something?  I have to manually start the next script once the directory changes?

Comment: This post got marked as a duplicate.  I don't think it's a duplicate of that question.  I had found that question and it deals with "cd" which my script doesn't do.  It's the application I call that changes the directory.  If I ran this script manually in the prompt, it would change directory after the first line... as it runs in a script, it changes directory at the end of the script run.